# How to use Augmented reality (AR) in ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, augmented-reality, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

How to use Augmented reality in ionic 2 for finding nearest location through camera GPS.when i open camera through APP.It should show all nearest location on the camera
Thank you